# Will there be a problem if I use more than 2 files in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

This is the code saved in discord_py_bot.py

```
@bot.command()
async def 눈뽕(ctx):
    print(ctx.guild.id)
    global nun
    global enter
    if not enter:
        sever = (ctx.guild.id)
        if sever in loadtruesever:
            nun = True
            enter = True
            print("nun = true")
            msg =  await ctx.send('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1194102643665158187/1198481161593298984/11cd7e6d772cfb2c.gif?ex=65d1848f&is=65bf0f8f&hm=14a06d28529cdd7c710f07bfe7e833e00be0a33f206fc6dbaa8c67275b6831d1&\n 이 메세지는 3초후 삭제 돼요!')
            time.sleep(3)
            await msg.delete()
        else:
            nun = False
            enter = True
            print("nun = False")
            await ctx.send("이 서버는 눈뽕 기능이 꺼저 있습니다!")
    else:
        if nun:
            msg =  await ctx.send('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1194102643665158187/1198481161593298984/11cd7e6d772cfb2c.gif?ex=65d1848f&is=65bf0f8f&hm=14a06d28529cdd7c710f07bfe7e833e00be0a33f206fc6dbaa8c67275b6831d1&\n 이 메세지는 3초후 삭제 돼요!')
            time.sleep(3)
            await msg.delete()
        elif not nun:
            await ctx.send("이 서버는 눈뽕 기능이 꺼저 있습니다!")

@bot.command()
async def 눈뽕설정(ctx , * , a: str):
    global nun
    if a is None:     
        pass
    elif a == "on":
        nun = True
        on(ctx.guild.id)
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="눈뽕 명령어가 켜젔습니다!", description="다시 끄려면 !눈뽕설정 off 를 입력 해주세요!", colour=discord.Colour.blue()))
    elif a == "off":
        nun = False
        off(ctx.guild.id)
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="눈뽕 명령어가 꺼젔습니다!", description="다시 켜려면 !눈뽕설정 on 를 입력 해주세요!", colour=discord.Colour.blue()))
```

And this code is saved in DB.py

```
truesever = [] 
import json
loadtruesever = []

def on(a):
    if a not in truesever:
        truesever.append(a)
        with open('databa.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(truesever, f)
        with open('databa.json', 'r') as f:
            loadtruesever = json.load(f)
        print(loadtruesever)

def off(a):
    try:
        amogus = truesever.index(a)
        del truesever[amogus]
        with open('databa.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(truesever, f)
        with open('databa.json', 'r') as f:
            loadtruesever = json.load(f)
        print(loadtruesever)
    except ValueError:
        print("이미 꺼저 있잖아")
        with open('databa.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(truesever, f)
        with open('databa.json', 'r') as f:
            loadtruesever = json.load(f)
```

And there is a json file where the server ID is stored.

The server ID is saved in the json file, but when !눈뽕 is entered,
nun = False was output.

The server ID is saved in the json file, but nun = False is displayed.

Please tell me how to make nun = true appear.

Answer (score 0):

No, there wont be any problem in the code you provided. The above code will work smoothly.